# Does over-training reduce muscle mass?

Tags: physical-fitness

[BodyBuilding.com](http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/teen-russ1.htm) and [LiveStrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/305159-why-are-my-muscles-getting-smaller-after-lifting-weights/) claim that over-training (training excessively/while being sore) reduces muscle mass.

LiveStrong says:

> Over-training describes a state where your muscles are not given sufficient time between workouts to recover and grow. If you train too hard and too often, the anabolic process of hypertrophy cannot occur. Include a couple of days off from exercise per week and include periodic phases of lighter or less frequent workouts to avoid becoming over-trained.

BodyBuilding.com says:

> If you overtrain your muscles will not grow in size or strength and can actually get weaker or smaller.

It seems counter-intuitive that the body reduces the volume/power of the muscle that is clearly in frequent and excessive use.

Is there any validity to this claim?

Comment: Why does that seem counterintuitive? If you use your muscle tissue faster than it can be replaced and augmented, why *wouldn't* you wind up with less? I bike > 150 miles a week and my best days are after I've had a day or two off. My worst and weakest are after I've gone four or five days without a break.

Comment: Experiment time: I will start hitting the gym and train really really hard. Then I will keep on training and report back on whether this happens or not. It's for science!

Comment: @Mooz make it a paper and publish it and you'll get the bounty. But I am afraid that 6 days is a rather close call and might be a bit short for the experiment ;)